# Making the YouTube JS API work with iOS, dealing with embedSWF?

Tags: javascript, ios, youtube, youtube-api, swfobject

I'm working with the JS API for YouTube and for displaying the video player, [use of embedSWF is recommended by Google in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Embedding), like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>    

  <div id="ytapiplayer">
    You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3","ytapiplayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);

  </script>
```

While this works fine on my computer and Android devices, on iOS the *ytapiplayer* div does not turn into an embedded player but instead just displays its original contents, i.e. the error message saying Flash player 8+ and JS are required.

Is it possible to get my this working on iOS? If so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should try new YouTube iframe Player API? https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

It works with mobile devices without thinking about Flash.
Embedding example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    var videoBox = document.getElementById('video1');
    videoBox.ytplayer = new YT.Player(videoBox, {
        videoId: 'kXDiGtgPL6E',
        playerVars: {
            //controls: 0,
            wmode:'transparent'
        },
        height: '200',
        width: '320'
    });
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you. My OnStateChange functions are all getting called twice now, however. Messes everything up as my script thinks two videos have already been player (state==ended), while it's only been one in fact. 

This is pretty much the chain of events:
Player Ended -> Initialize New Video -> Player Ended (wrong) -> Initialize Next Video -> Plays succesfully (but the previous video got skipped 'cause the API reported it had already ended before it could even start to play)

No idea why this is happening...

Comment: Maybe you can put your code to jsfiddle? You can also re-embed player after each video as a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I did this exact thing a few months ago for a project...

Javascript, very similar to what you have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var flashvars = {};
                flashvars.youTubeVideo = "VitQwgsBq-w";
                flashvars.controllerAlign = "top";
                flashvars.queTo = "0";
                flashvars.controlBarAlpha = ".3";
            var params = {};
            var attributes = {};
                swfobject.embedSWF("images/youTubeLoader.swf", "youTubeDiv", "250px", "200px", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

What swfobject.js is going to do is look for an HTML div named "youTubeDiv" and replace all of it's contents with an SWF youtube player

(i did this b/c the iframe solution had z-index issues with an HTML5 project i was working on)

Now the HTML:

```
    <div id="youTubeDiv">
            <iframe width="250px" height="200px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VitQwgsBq-w" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

Comment: This shows the video, but makes the player unresponsive to any API action (playing new videos, change of volume, event changes, etc.).