# VideoJS / YoutubeJS not playing on mobile device

Tags: android, mobile, video

On my website (ryancreason.com) my VideoJS player at the top of the page works to play Youtube videos with YouTubeJS, unless I'm on my mobile device (android). The loading icon happens, but the player just stays blank. I've tried searching for a reason & fix, but to no avail. Any ideas? Here is the code for my player:

```
    <video id="videoSamples" class="video-js video-js-small vjs-default-skin" autoplay muted loop preload="auto" playsInline quality="" width="100%" height="auto" data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNpg1LD1t_Y" }'>
</video>
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Check this out?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799384/making-the-youtube-js-api-work-with-ios-dealing-with-embedswf